# Converting Audio File to Digital Voltages

Tags: microcontroller

I am beginning a project where I am using a microcontroller (TI's MSP432) as a sequencer in an electronic drum machine. I have already written code that successfully samples the output of a few drum circuits, via ADC, and I have a few audio samples that I would also like to integrate into the project.

Currently, I am wondering how to go about converting these audio files (.WAV files specifically) into digital voltages that I can combine with my ADC results to form drum tracks.

Any assistance that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert the .WAV file to a PDM waveform or similar?

Comment: here is a description of the wav file format .... http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: You may have to get used to somes things done backwards and forwards with Most Sig. Byte 1st (bigendian) and Least Sig. Byte 1st (little endian) due to Murphy's Law. ( if anything can be reversed it will be)

Comment: Audacity or something to convert WAVs to RAW binaries with specified sample rate and byte order (if applicable) may be helpful. You could then load those resulting binaries into some memory either on the micro or external to it, while having to do no 'translation' at all at runtime. It still depends on what your actual requirements are - what sound quality is required, how long samples and how many, etcetera.

Comment: what are you wanting to extract from the wav file?